How to find the history of a particular NOTAM?
I have a tower at 1434 feet MSL and it has inoperative tower lights for at least 2 years. I can find a current NOTAM but would like to find out the history of the NOTAM. The current NOTAM is:

NOTAM #: 10/003
Class: Obstruction
Status: Active
Issue Date UTC: 10/06/2024 0856
Start Date UTC: 10/06/2024 0856
End Date UTC: 11/05/2024 0001
!OPN 10/003 OPN OBST TOWER LGT (ASR 1200772) 330411.00N0840839.00W (9.3NM NE OPN) 1434.7FT (315.0FT AGL) U/S 2410060856-2411050001

Thanks for any help on this history

Does that help? Is there a public NOTAM archive that's searchable by airport?
